# connecting ionic4/socket.io to expressjs net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: angular, express, socket.io, ionic-native

I get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` all the time, even when the server is not running.

When running the application through my browser it works fine, but, then through the device and ran natively I get the error above.

I feel like I have tried everything to resolve this issue. I have read so so so many stack overflow questions with the same issue. and none of them have helped.

app.module:

```
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http:localhost:8080', options: {}};
```

note: above I have also tried:

> 'https://localhost:8080'
>
> 'https://localhost:8080/'
>
> 'http://localhost:8080/'
>
> '127.0.0.1:8080'
>
> '127.0.0.1:8080/'
>
> 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'
>
> 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'
>
> 'https://127.0.0.1:8080'
>
> 'https://127.0.0.1:8080/'

socketio server:

```
const app = require('express')();
const PORT = process.env.CHAT_PORT || 3000;
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const server = require('http').createServer(app , {origins: 'http://127.0.0.1:8100'}); 
const io = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(server);
const SocketManager = require('./lib/SocketManager');
```

note: I have tried all the same variations as above in the `origins:` except changing the port since my Ionic 4 app is running on Port 8100. I have also tried not including the `origins:`

my SocketService:

```
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
    export class ChatService {

      constructor(private socket: Socket) {}

      public sendMessage(msg: any){
        this.socket.emit('new-message', msg);

      }

      public getMessages = () => {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
          this.socket.on('new-message', messageObj => {
            observer.next(messageObj);
          })
        })
      }
    }
```

What I am expecting it to do is connect, and for my server to register that there has been a connection.

Thanks for any help

UPDATE: I've configured my config.xml as such:

```
   <content original-src="index.html" src="http://192.168.1.38:8100" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

no such luck. still blocked though

Answer (score 1):

Once i would smash my laptop for this error after trying and searching i got the answer as following

***Firstly***

To run it on your device you have to put you `IP Adress` like `192.168.1.2` in your application, You can get by opening `CMD` and type `ipconfig` if you are using windows, So in your app it must be

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://IP_ADDRESS:8080', options: {}};
```

***Secondly***

Which was my problem actually, Please go to firewall and disable it just for testing,If you want to produce your app you have to enable only the port your app running on

> Please note that you have to turn it off for accepting the connection on your specified port

***Finally***

Make sure that your local server accepting request from your client-side, You can use `Cors` external package.

To install it:

```
npm install cors --save
```

To use it:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*', //Or some origins you can specify
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}));
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer and will be looking into resolving that!!! still wanna throw my computer! But, when you are talking about the firewall are you also referring with an OS X?

Comment: Yes for sure , You have to turn it off

Comment: I've been trying your suggestions and can't seem to get it to work. I changed the config in my app.module to be `'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'`, disabled my firewall, and set cors on my server to allow any connection with just `app.use(cors())` I solved it once, but then I saved and the issue came back 

Comment: Please dont use ``127.0....`` as it's equal to ``localhost`` , make sure you use your IP adress, For ``cors()`` try it as i mention in the answer , i mean set origin to * or ``localhost:`` + PORT , PORT refers to the port that your app using

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the issue. The issue is stupid enough and I am ashamed to have solved it like this. But the issue was that when I was trying to connect the phone to the server I was using the IP address of localhost `127.0.0.1:8080` which on the CLIENT side is looking inward to itself! What I needed to do was go to Apple->System Preferences->Network and then use the IP address from:

> Wi-Fi is connected to MOVISTAR_PLUS_52B1 
>   and has the IP address 192.168.X.XX.

put that into my config as such:
`const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 192.168.X.XX, options: {}};`